# Copying subversion repository to new shared drive

Tags: svn, ubuntu-10.04

We are migrating our data to a new H-NAS server.  So, I planned to move our subversion repositories to a shared drive in the H-NAS server.

Instead of moving the data using `svnadmin dump <reponame> > reponame.file`,  I used 
`cp -prf /source/<reponame> /dest/`.

When I did this everything works, but still I would like to know if this is the right way to do it.  Also, when I copied the repositories, the data size was more in the copy.  Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

> is it a right way of doing it

Yes

> when I copied the repo's the data size was more.

Text representation of history require more space than binary

PS: It's bad idea in common to have repo on non-local drive with file:/// access to it

Comment: I used cp -prf command to move the repo. & Can I know why its bad idea to keep in non-local drive. Any specific reason please.

Answer (score 0):

The size on disk of data will differ according to the filesystem used and several other factors.  For this reason, comparisons of disk space used are not often meaningful.  You did indeed do this correctly (you can simply copy the repository storage if your intention is to change where it is hosted from).